# cURL upload more files

Tags: php, curl

From manual to any webservice I need construct code in PHP. I have testing environment, and I know that when I post one image, it works well; but when I need to post more images, it doesn't work properly. In manual is this:

```
curl -v -s -u username:password \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json" \
-F "image=@img1.jpeg;type=image/jpeg" \
-F "image=@img2.jpeg;type=image/jpeg" \
-XPUT 'https://www.example.com/seller-api/sellers/12/ads/217221/images'
```

Here is code that works for one file upload:

```
$sql[2] = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE car_id='".$car['id']."'";
$result[2] = mysql_query($sql[2]);
if(mysql_num_rows($result[2])>0){
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    while($img = mysql_fetch_array($result[2])){
        $file = '@inzerce/'.$img['nazev'];
        $post['image'] = $file.";type=image/jpeg";
    }
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: services.mobile.de','Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=vjrLeiXjJaWiU0JzZkUPO1rMcE2HQ-n7XsSx', 'Accept: application/vnd.com.example.api+json'));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, TRUE);
    $result2 = curl_exec($request);
    $info2 = curl_getinfo($request);
    curl_close($request);    
}
```

But when I need to upload more files, only the last one uploads to the server. When I try to insert image into array (for example: $post[$img['id']]['image']), the server this file not accepts. I tried rewrite $post['image'] to $post['image'.$img['id']], but it doesn't work either. I tried it in bash, something else than image doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you try using `$post['image'][] = $file.";type=image/jpeg";`

Comment: I posted a working example for the mobile.de API here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45281102/8306775

Answer (score 0):

You must pass it in an array, here is the quick example

```
<?php

//Initialise the cURL var
$ch = curl_init();

//Get the response from cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);

//Set the Url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://s/');

//Create a POST array with the file in it
$postData = array(
    'testData[0]' => new \CURLFile( __FILE__ ),
    'testData[1]' => new \CURLFile( __FILE__ ),
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

// Execute the request
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```