# Convert PUT using -F option cURL command to cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, put

I want to convert a cURL command line that works properly, to a PHP code.
Here is my command line :

```
curl -k -v -x api.test.sandbox.mobile.de:8080 -u xxx:yyy -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Accept: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json" -F "image1=@1000_1.JPG;type=image/jpg" -X PUT https://services.mobile.de/seller-api/sellers/1086/ads/943627/images
```

This works properly, I've tried to convert the cURL command line into this cURL PHP code :

```
 $ch = curl_init();

    $proxy = PROXY_MOBILE_DE;
    $proxy_port = PROXY_PORT_MOBILE_DE;
    $loginpassw = LOGINPASSWD_MOBILE_DE;

    $post_data = array(
            "image1" => '@1000_1.JPG',
            "type" => 'image/jpg'
    );

    $url='https://services.mobile.de/seller-api/sellers/'.$sellerId.'/ads/'.$vehicleAdId.'/images';

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $loginpassw);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        echo "Error: ".$info['http_code']." // ".$info['url'];
    }

    if ($data=='')
        echo 'Success ';
    else
        echo 'Failure'.$data;
    echo "<br/>";

    curl_close($ch);
```

But I receive an error like "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found". Any idea where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

```
$post_data = array(
    "image1" => '@1000_1.JPG',
    "type" => 'image/jpg'
);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://services.mobile.de/seller-api/sellers/1086/ads/943627/images");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "api.test.sandbox.mobile.de:8080");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xxx:yyy");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";
$headers[] = "Accept: application/vnd.de.mobile.api+json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Hi Hasta Dhana, it looks like you get this code using https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/, am I wrong ? I run this converter too, but I'm skeptical on the result, as I dont' see any reference to -F option in the PHP code generated...

Comment: Ok, I've just tried this new code. I receive an error "the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"...

Comment: @HastaDana : do you have any other idea on what is wrong with my code ? I updated my post with the cURL PHP code...

Comment: Hi, could you try removing the `http_build_query` and see what's the result ?

Comment: Have found a post that was the same as mine !!
Here is the answer of my issue : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431824/curl-send-images-with-boundary-to-rest-api

Comment: @Dersime apparently you worked on mobile.de API, same to me. I have a question : do you have uploaded images with a PUT (after the creation of the ad), or a with a POST (at the creation of the ad) ? because your post to the stackoverflow forum, was related to a PUT request, and I would prefer to upload images with a POST. If you could help me it would be great ! thanks !